# Independent events imply "countably independent" events?

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification

We call a family of events $\{A_\alpha\}$ of a probability space *mutually independent* iff, for every finite subset $\{A_i\}$ we have $$P(\bigcap A_i) = \prod P(A_i)$$

In my book they prove that *mutually independent* is not implied by *pairwise independent*. So it made me wonder if *mutually independent* would imply the following, which the writter called *countably independent*, whenever the infinite product is defined: for every sequence $\{A_n\}$, does the following hold (assuming the sequence of products converges)?: $$P(\bigcap A_n) = \prod_{k=1}^{+\infty} P(A_k)$$

The writter tried to prove this with apparent success:

$$RHS = \lim_{n\to \infty} \prod_{i=1}^nP( A_i) = \lim_{n\to \infty} P(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i) = (1)$$

Put $B_k = \bigcap_{i=1}^k A_i$. Then $B_0 \supseteq B_1 \supseteq ...$ is a monotonically decreasing sequence. The writter uses the following lemma:

Lemma: If $\{B_n\}$ is monotonically decreasing then $\lim B_n$ exists, $\lim_{n\to \infty} P(B_n) = P(\lim B_n)$ and $\lim B_n = \bigcap_{i=1}^{+\infty}B_i$

The writter omits the proof as this is probably well known. Using this we get that $$(1) = \lim_{n \to +\infty} P(B_n) = P(\lim B_n) = P(\bigcap_{i=1}^{+\infty}B_i) = P(\bigcap_{i=1}^{+\infty}\bigcap_{j=1}^{i}A_j) = P(\bigcap A_n)$$ $\square$

Is this proof correct? Can it be improved?

Comment: It is correct. It is not clear what exactly your confusioin is and what kind of help you need.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy just paranoid that there might be some mistake i didn't catch